# How to call the method of unknown class in MQL?

Tags: class, function-pointers, void-pointers, mql5

I've a `Collection` class which aims to store different kind of objects, however I'd like to call specific method name which these classes share (e.g. `ToString()`).

Here is my attempt:

```
class Collection {
  public:
    void *data[];

    void Collection() {}
    void ~Collection() {
      for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize(data); i++) {
        if (CheckPointer(data[i]) == POINTER_DYNAMIC) delete data[i];
      }
    }

    void *Add(void *_object) {
      uint _size = ArraySize(data);
      ArrayResize(data, _size + 1, 100);
      data[_size] = _object;
      return _object;
    }

    string ToString(string _dlm = ",") {
      string _out = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize(data); i++) {
        if (CheckPointer(data[i]) == POINTER_DYNAMIC) {
          _out += ((void *) data[i]).ToString(); // @fixme: Syntax error.
        }
      }
      return _out;
    }

};
```

However using `((void *) data[i]).ToString()` syntax fails with:

> 'ToString' - member function not defined Collection.mqh

How can I call a `ToString()` method for each stored object?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it should be something like `collection.toString()` where `collection` is an object of your `class Collection`. Then each object that you add to your collection should implement this function... Maybe it is easier to mention some superclass that supports `toString()` (or interface with this method) and make sure that you add only correct objects? This also makes your code free of unexpected errors in runtime.

Also `CArrayObj` is [at your disposal](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/datastructures/carrayobj) with most functions, if you need `toString()` or any other function then you can simply extend basic class. Maybe the only disadvantage of the default collection is that it stores `CObject`-inherited objects.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating [an abstract class](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/oop/abstract_type) where all classes can share the same virtual method. For example:

```
class Object {
  public:
    virtual string ToString() = NULL;
};

class Foo : public Object {
  public:
    virtual string ToString() {
      return "Foo";
    };
};

class Bar : public Object {
  public:
    virtual string ToString() {
      return "Bar";
    };
};
```

Then in the `Collection` class the following method:

```
virtual string ToString(string _dlm = ",") {
  string _out = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize(data); i++) {
    if (CheckPointer(data[i]) == POINTER_DYNAMIC) {
      _out += ((Object *) data[i]).ToString() + _dlm;
    }
  }
  return _out;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Collection *objects;
objects = new Collection;
Foo *foo = new Foo();
Bar *bar = new Bar();
objects.Add(foo);
objects.Add(bar);
Print(objects.ToString());
delete objects;
```